# Reading value removes characters in JSonNet

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to read a date time string from a JValue but it gets changed as its read..

```
{
  "updated": "2012-12-12T00:00:00Z",
}

JSON["updated"].Value<String>() = 12/12/2012 00:00:00
```

the above JSON string is found when I inspect the JSON object.  Any ideas why it's doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably resolving it to a DateTime internally and doing a DateTime.ToString.

Try

```
JSON["updated"].Value<DateTime>().ToString("your format")
```